# Count matches across multiple columns in Excel

Tags: excel, excel-formula

There is a table with months and text IDs of users who were active in that month

| January | February | March |
| --- | --- | --- |
| abx8bn | xcwq23MO | wesXT23n |
| Rtb8ui | abx8bn | abx8bn |

I need to calculate how many users who were active in January were also active in February, and out of those - how many were active in March. In other words, how many IDs are same in January and February, and how many IDs in March match with them. What is the best way to do it?

Expected output is like a funnel, e.g.

|  |  |
| --- | --- |
| January | 10000 users |
| February | 5600 *(out of 10000)* |
| March | 2900 *(out of 5600)* |

`COUNTIFS()` seems not to work.
`=COUNT(MATCH())` works but only for two columns.

Comment: So a user who is active in Febuary and March (but not in January) doesn't count?

Comment: That's right. I want to calculate a funnel from January 'cohort'

Comment: What about a user who is active in January and March (but not in Febuary): does he count?

Comment: That also doesn't count. Only people active in all three are needed

Answer (score 3):

You can try:

[image]

Formula in `E2`:

```
=BYCOL(REDUCE(A2:A8,B1:C1,LAMBDA(x,y,LET(z,TAKE(x,,-1),HSTACK(x,FILTER(z,COUNTIF(INDEX(B2:C8,,MATCH(y,B1:C1,0)),z)))))),LAMBDA(c,ROWS(TOCOL(c,3))))
```

Answer (score 2):

What about this approach, based on the formula:

```
=IF(ISERROR(MATCH(D3;B$3:B$8;0));"";D3)
```

Hereby a screenshot:

[image]

Row 2 contains the formula texts of row 3, row 10 contains the formula texts of row 9.

In column "D", all users, present in January, are shown, using the `UNIQUE()` function (if you are sure that you have only one user entry in January, this can be replaced by `=A3`).
In the following column (the one for February), the `Match()` function is used, in combination with an `IF(ISERROR())`, for checking availability in February.
The next column (the one for March), is the interesting one: as you are only interested in the March entries, which are also present in January AND February, you can simply rely on the results you already have in column "E" and build further on that, leading to the mentioned screenshot.

Why is that last column so interesting?
Well, you can continue creating columns for the next months of the year, and once done, you only need to write the functions for January and February and as for the next months, you can just drag to the next column ("F3" is the same as "F2", dragged to the right).

Answer (score 2):

You could also do it like this (but only if the usernames are unique in each month):

```
=LET(range,A2:C8,
seq,SEQUENCE(1,COLUMNS(range)),
rows,ROWS(range),
MAP(seq,LAMBDA(c,LET(pRange,INDEX(range,1,1):INDEX(range,rows,c),SUM(--(COUNTIF(pRange,pRange)=c))/c))))
```

or

```
=LET(range,A2:C8,
seq,SEQUENCE(1,COLUMNS(range)),
rows,ROWS(range),
MAP(seq,LAMBDA(c,LET(pRange,INDEX(range,1,1):INDEX(range,rows,c),qRange,CHOOSECOLS(range,c),SUM(--(COUNTIF(pRange,qRange)=c))))))
```

[image]

To do it with non-unique columns, you couldn't use Countif in the same way but you could define a function myCountIf:

```
=LAMBDA(array1,array2,MAP(array2, LAMBDA(c, IF(c = "", 0, SUM(--(array1 = c))))))
```

and use

```
=LET(range,A2:C8,
seq,SEQUENCE(1,COLUMNS(range)),
uniques,DROP(REDUCE("",seq,LAMBDA(a,c,IFERROR(HSTACK(a,UNIQUE(INDEX(range,,c))),""))),,1),
MAP(seq,LAMBDA(c,SUM(--(myCountIf(TAKE(uniques,,c),INDEX(uniques,,c))=c)))))
```

Answer (score 1):

### Count Matches of Matches of... Across Columns

```
=LET(data,A1:L21,
    GetMatches,LAMBDA(data1,data2,LET(s,TOCOL(data2,1),
        TOCOL(XLOOKUP(TOCOL(data1,1),s,s),3))),
    s,SEQUENCE(COLUMNS(data)),
    h,TOCOL(TAKE(data,1)),
    d,DROP(data,1),
    mu,IFNA(DROP(REDUCE("",s,LAMBDA(rr,r,LET(
        c,CHOOSECOLS(d,r),
        HSTACK(rr,IF(r=1,c,
            GetMatches(CHOOSECOLS(rr,r),c)))))),,1),""),
    mc,BYCOL(mu,LAMBDA(r,SUM(--(r<>"")))),
    mr,BYROW(s,LAMBDA(r,LET(
        c,CHOOSECOLS(mc,r),
        IF(r=1,c&" users",c&" (out of "&CHOOSECOLS(mc,r-1)&")")))),
HSTACK(h,mr))
```

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Thanks everyone for the answers!

Went a bit of a roundabout way around this.

[image]

1. Put all unique IDs into one column
2. Write a formula that checks if the ID is in the corresponding month

`=IFERROR(VLOOKUP($A2;'User IDs by month'!A:A;1;FALSE)=$A2;FALSE)` for January
`=IFERROR(VLOOKUP($A2;'User IDs by month'!B:B;1;FALSE)=$A2;FALSE)` for February
etc.

3. Then a simple if-formula in a separate column checking if the ID is in all the months you need

`=IF(AND($B2=TRUE;$C2=TRUE;$D2=TRUE;$E2=TRUE);1;0)` for 4 months

4. Fill down to all IDs, then SUM the 1s in column

Excel kicked and screamed trying to do this for 500k rows, but hey, it works